# Unable to compile Java presentation code after upgrade

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, web8, upgrade, broker

I have recently upgraded from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8 CU1. The CMS seems to work fine however I am having difficulties compiling my presentation side Java code against Web8 libraries.

In particular I was using some class from `com.tridion.meta` package, but I can't seem to find those classes in the Web8 jars anymore. I was using `com.tridion.meta.ComponentMetaFactory` and `com.tridion.meta.CustomMeta`. I can see `com.tridion.meta.ComponentMetaFactory` in the jars but not `com.tridion.meta.CustomMeta`.

Can someone please let me know if these class files have been refactored into other packages? If they've been deprecated then what is the replacement for these?